# Unexpected Token Errors with ColdFusion Form Regex Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, coldfusion

I'm trying to do some date validation using regex with CFFORMS, but getting a javascript syntax error that prevents validation from working correctly at all. Running CF10 and see the javascript error on all browsers.

The date format should be MM/DD/YY.

I've tried two different types of regex patterns below without success.

```
<cfset today = DateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yy") />
```

**Attempt # 1**

```
<cfinput type="text" name="orderDate" id="orderDate" maxlength="8" size="12" validate="regex" pattern="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}" message="Please enter a Date Order Entered in MM/DD/YY format" value="#today#" />
```

Error message is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

**Attempt # 2**

```
<cfinput type="text" name="orderDate" id="orderDate" maxlength="8" size="12" validate="regex" pattern="^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$" message="Please enter a Date Order Entered in MM/DD/YY format" value="#today#" />
```

Error message is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Sounds like ColdFusion doesn't allow `{n}` to specify number of repetitions.  Try: `[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @Sam This time, I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , error message trying that. Here is the javascript output that gets generated by CF on the client side:           //form element orderDate'REGEX' validation checks
        if (!_CF_checkregex(_CF_this['orderDate'].value, /[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/, false))
        {
            _CF_onError(_CF_this, "orderDate", _CF_this['orderDate'].value, "Please enter a Date Order Entered in MM/DD/YY format");
            _CF_error_exists = true;
        }

Comment: Try escaping the `/` with `\/`, I guess they add in their own delimiters.

Comment: Don't use `cfinput` or anyother client side functionality of ColdFusion. Use a real JS lib - like jQuery - that has plugins for handling client side validation.

Comment: @Sam Escaping / fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seemed like there were 2 errors:

- ColdFusion added in `/` delimiters, causing the `/` in between `mm/dd/yy` to create errors.
- ColdFusion doesn't support `{n}` for repetition, so you must replace `[0-9]{2}` with `[0-9][0-9]`

Final expression:

```
[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]
```